# Material exchange in Destiny

Tags: destiny, xbox-one

Could someone explain to me how the material exchange works in the actually destiny game. The two vendors I'm told to go to give me material in exchange for marks. Am I missing something? I'm also playing on Xbox One of that changes anything.

Comment: The linked duplicate question has answers which are no longer true.  They were, but the end-of-year patch changed things.  Now, materials exchange only works the other way: you can *buy* materials, but you can't sell them.

Comment: @CPerkins I have updated the linked question's accepted answer to correctly answer this question while retaining the old information.

Comment: @turbo well done.   In an unselfish world, I'd delete my answer there, but systems work as they work. ;)